# How to hide a raw in view.php file using Yii2 Framework

Tags: yii, hide, raw

I have this raw in my view.php file:

```
[
              'attribute' => 'Descrizione',
                'format' => 'html',
                'value' => function ( $model ) {
                return nl2br($model->Descrizione);
              },
              'label' => 'Descrizione',
                ],
```

What I want is to hide the entire field if the value don't contains any character, so if is = "" OR is NULL. So I want to hide the entire field "Descrizione".
Which is the option that I have to add in this code?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Gridview or DetailView ?

If DetailView, try :

```
[
  'attribute' => 'Descrizione',
  'label' => 'Descrizione',
  'visible' => !empty($model->Descrizione),
  'format' => 'ntext',
],
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **options** attribute to set a CSS style.
for example:

```
empty($model->Descrizione)?'hidden':''
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield

Eg:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Descrizione',['options'=>['class'=>empty($model->Descrizione)?'hidden':'']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'disabled' => true]) ?>
```

Make sure the class "hidden" is actually defined - if you are using bootstrap you can use d-none

Comment: Thank you. And where can I use it? In my attribute code directly in the view?